# Semantic markup of navigation and search area

Tags: html, nav, semantic-markup

I'm trying to learn semantic HTML5 markup by converting a simple site I once made for an old magazine. Now I've come to the navigation and search area. You should be able to select a specific article to read or search within the database. There are two tabs and when the first one is active you see the contents of the selected issue like this:

[image: Screenshot]

When clicking on the search tab you come to a search field, like so:

[image: Screenshot]

And when you've made a search the results are presented in a similar fashion to the contents above:

[image: Screenshot]

The present markup looks something like this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="tabs">
        <div class="tab">Browse</div>
        <div class="tab">Search</div>
    </div>
    <div id="browse">
        <form>
            <div>
                <label>Year:</label>
                <select>
                    <option>1985</option>
                </select>   
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Issue:</label>
                <select>
                    <option>1</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="contents">
            <h1>Contents</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="search">
        <form>
            <label>Search for anything:</label>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Ok">
        </form>
        <div id="results">
            <!--    
                <h1>Sorry, we couldn't find anything.</h1> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Various stuff</a></li>
                </ul>
            -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As for semantic elements, I have considered various options, none of which seems like ***the*** solution.

My first problem is whether I should wrap the whole thing inside `nav` tags or just the browse part, or even just the contents part of the browse part. I'm somewhat inclined to consider the whole thing a single main navigational area.

As for the inner parts, I assume they could be divided into `section` elements, primarily a browse `section` and a search `section`. If so, it would have been nice to get the tab text into those sections as headings, but that will complicate things presentational-wise too much (I know I shouldn't worry about CSS and JS at this stage, but I do). And sections without headings seem like a bad idea.

Another option would be to regard the div#contents and the div#results as subsections. One problem with that is that the results area doesn't have any content until a search has been made.

I can think of some other options as well, but I don't see any point in mentioning them all just to show research effort. I would still need just as much help. And I'd appreciate it too.

Comment: Where does this element appear? In the sidebar of every page? Or is it (part of) the main content of a page (e.g., the home page)?

Comment: It appears on the left side (or occupies the full width on narrower screens like mobiles) below the header of every page, and when a user clicks on a link in the #contents list or the #results list the selected article is displayed to the right of (or below) this element in what I've called the `main` element. That is: nav/search in "LEFT/TOP", display article in "RIGHT/BOTTOM" in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k27vLwa0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first problem is whether I should wrap the whole thing inside nav
>   tags or just the browse part...

Looking at the [definition of the nav element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) in the HTML5 spec

> The `nav` element represents a section of a page that links to other
>   pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.

...tells us that it should be used for the `id="browse"` element.
I think it should also wrap the form because it contains controls to filter these navigation items.

The `id="search"` element should, according to the [aria role `search`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#search)

> A landmark region that contains a collection of items and objects
>   that, as a whole, combine to create a search facility.

Get a `role="search"`.

The tab list on the top should get the proper aria treatment for tabs with `role="tablist"` and `role="tab"`. As shown in this snippet:

```
<div id="tabs" role="tablist">
    <div class="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="browse">Browse</div>
    <div class="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="search">Search</div>
</div>
```